# Python can not import pywifi

Tags: python

I have install pywifi module and it success, when I try to import pywifi,I got this error.

```
>>> import pywifi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pywifi/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .wifi import PyWiFi
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pywifi/wifi.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .iface import Interface
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pywifi/iface.py", line 15, in <module>
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

someone can help me?

Comment: Are you on a mac? Pywifi only supports linux and windows.  If not try python 3.

Comment: yes, I'm on a mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which python version are you running? It might be because it is installed as a Python 3 package and you're running Python 2.7 or the opposite.

To specifically install the package for Python 3, try entering this command:

```
pip3 install pywifi
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install pywifi
```

To specifically install the package for Python 2, try entering this command:

`pip2 install pywifi`

or

`python -m pip install pywifi`

Answer (score 0):

I got similar errors, from the error message, I tried to install those packages that pywifi seemed to depend on, i.e., I ran

```
    pip install comtypes
    pip install iface
```

then it worked.